# Javascript longhand if condition not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new at javaScript and I am having trouble understanding longhand and shorthand of the if condition. I have read about them and I thought I understood but somehow the simple dropdown menu I am working on fails when I work with the longhand statement.

HTML code:

```
<ul class="nav-menu">    
<li onclick="dropDown(this)">
    <a href="#" >Birds</a>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="">Ratites</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fowl</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Neoaves</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li onclick="dropDown(this)">
    <a href="#">Dogs</a>
    <ul class="menu1">
        <li><a href="">Big</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Noizy</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS code:

```
a {
    color: #06c;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: pink;
    float: left;
}

li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    display: none;
}

.menu1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript shorthand version:

```
function dropDown(li) {
    var submenu = li.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    submenu.style.display = submenu.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";    
}
```

JavaScript longhand version:

```
function dropDown(li) {
    var submenu = li.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    if( submenu.style.display == "block"){
        submenu.style.display="none";
    }
    else{
        submenu.style.display="block";
    }
}
```

Again, the shorthand works. What am I doing wrong in the longhand statement?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wkmd7h0r/24/

Comment: Looks like you just have an extra `}` at the end? http://jsfiddle.net/wkmd7h0r/25/ Voting to close as **a simple typographical error**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the console, you'll see the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`, which means, you have extra curly brace in your code.